# Limit of a line equation

Tags: limits

Here is the exact problem 
The equation of the circle which passes through the point $(2,0)$ and whose centre is the limit of point of intersection of the lines $3x+5y=1$ and         $((c+2)x + 5c^2 y =1)\quad$as c tends to 1

Comment: So what is exactly the question?

Comment: If you can find the other equation we can find the centre and then solve for the circle equation but the limit of the line equation is my doubt

Comment: When $c$ approaches 1, the lines become identical. Therefore in the "limit" case, the circle has a center that is on the line $3x+5y=1$. But with the information given, I don't see how a unique equation of a circle can be obtained

Comment: Why do people here consistently downvote classical geometry questions and puzzle questions? I happen to enjoy them and don't see why they are of any less value than verbally oriented questions.

Answer (score 1):

If we eed the limit, we need first to find if it exists and then to calculate it. So we need to solve the intersection problem and then look at limat as $c \rightarrow 1$.

Intersection of the lines $3x + 5y = 1$ and $(c + 2)x + 5c^2 y = 1$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 5 & | & 1\\ (c+2) & 5c^2 & | & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 5 & | & 1& ...\\ 0 & 15c^2-5(c+2) & | & 3 - (c+2)& 3 Row 2 - (c+2)Row 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 5 & | & 1& ...\\ 0 & 15c^2-5c-10 & | & 1-c& 3 Row 2 - (c+2)Row 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

At the point of intersection $ y = \frac {1-c}{15c^2 -5c - 10} = \frac{1-c}{5(3c^2 - c - 2)}= \frac{1-c}{5(3c+2)(c-1)}$

Noting that the author carefully designed this question so that the factoring would work out, at the intersection $y= \frac{1-c}{5(3c+2)(c-1)}= \frac{-1(c-1)}{5(3c+2)(c-1)}$

As long as $c \neq 1$ we can take the limit and say that as $c$ approaches 1, the value of y at the intersection is $y = \frac{-1}{5(3c+2)}$ which approaches $-1/25$ in the limit.

Substituting into the first equation, $3x + 5(-1/25) = 1$ so $3x - 1/5 = 1$, $3x = 6/5$, $x = 2/5$

The limiting point of intersection is therefore $(2/5, -1/25)$ and you can find the circle and finish off from there.

Comment: You're welcome. If you like it, you can accept the answer as the best. Apparently I get points for that.